# How to get unique values of a column in pyspark dataframe and store as new column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Basically I want to know how much a brand that certain customer buy in other dataset and rename it as change brand, here's what I did in Pandas

```
firstvalue=firstvalue.merge((pd.DataFrame(profile.groupby('msisdn')
                                          .handset_brand.nunique()
                                          .rename('hpbrand_change_num'))
                                          .reset_index()),how='left',on=['msisdn'])
```

Here's what I did (without merge) in pyspark

```
fd_subsprofile.groupBy("msisdn")\
              .handset_brand.nunique()\
              .withColumn('hpbrand_change_num')\
              .reset_index()
```

The error message

```
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'handset_brand'
```

Then, I try

```
fd_subsprofile.groupBy("msisdn").select("handset_brand").count().show()
```

The error message

```
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'select'
```

How to this in pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing can be done in Pyspark as below -

`nunique` equivalent - [countDistinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct.html) , `merge` equivalent - [Join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

profile_agg_sparkDF = profile.groupBy('id').agg(F.countDistinct(F.col('brand')).alias('change_brand'))

df = df.join(profile_agg_sparkDF
            ,df['id'] == profile_agg_sparkDF['id']
            ,'left'
        ).select(df['*'],profile_agg_sparkDF['change_brand'])
```

Comment: What does `F` mean?

Comment: Updated the answer to include the required import statement , do accept and upvote the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: `AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "hpbrand_change_num" among (msisdn, count(DISTINCT handset_brand AS `hpbrand_change_num`));'`

Comment: Updated the answer , the `alias` should come after `F.countDistinct(F.col('brand')).alias('change_brand_num')`

Comment: use the alias accordingly based on your code snippet , you ll be good to go towards the error

Comment: Other error, `AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "change_brand" among (msisdn, count(DISTINCT brand));'`  I guess it is better to close and make new question

Comment: this can be easily solved with an alias towards your `count(Distinct brand)` as `F.countDistinct('brand').alias('change_brand')`

The error signifies that the column does not exists as its currently named - `count(Distinct brand)`

Comment: Still `AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "change_brand" among (msisdn, count(DISTINCT brand));'` , Probably I have library/other syntax problem

Comment: Did u used alias?

Comment: Yes, I use `alias`, `withColumn` and `WithColumnRenamed`, thats why I plan to write another question on this